How to run dependence tasks concurrently with non-dependence ones, and tasks inside for loop?
I am learning asyncio and there is a problem of running a dependence task concurrently with non-dependence ones. So far I couldn't make it work. This is my code:
import asyncio
import random

def first_execution(choice):
   if choice==1:
      print(f"First result {choice}")
      return choice
   else:
      print(f"First result {0}")
      return 0

async def check_first_execution(result_from_first):
   # Computationally complex function which take a lot of time to compute
   await asyncio.sleep(10)
   print(f"First check of value {result_from_first} complete")

async def second_execution(result_from_first):
   # Moderately complex computation
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print(f"Second result {result_from_first+1}")
   return result_from_first+1

async def check_second_execution(result_from_second):
   # Computationally complex function which take a lot of time to compute
   await asyncio.sleep(10)
   print(f"Second check of value {result_from_second} complete")
   
async def third_execution(result_from_first):
   # Moderately complex computation
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print(f"Third result {result_from_first+2}")
   return result_from_first+2

async def check_third_execution(result_from_third):
   # Computationally complex function which take a lot of time to compute
   await asyncio.sleep(10)
   print(f"Third check of value {result_from_third} complete")


async def main():
   choice = random.choice([0, 1])
   result_from_first = first_execution(choice)
   
   # First part
   coroutine_1 = check_first_execution(result_from_first)
   if result_from_first==1:
      coroutine_2 = second_execution(result_from_first)
      results = await asyncio.gather(coroutine_1, coroutine_2)
   elif result_from_first==0:
      coroutine_3 = third_execution(result_from_first)
      results = await asyncio.gather(coroutine_1, coroutine_3)

   # Second part
   list_results_from_first = [result_from_first+i for i in range(5)]
   for first_result in list_results_from_first:
      second_result = await second_execution(first_result)
      check_second = await check_second_execution(second_result)

asyncio.run(main())

In the first part (# First part), my code works but it only runs sequentially, meaning: first_execution -> check_first_execution -> second_execution (with choice==1) :
    >> First result 1
    >> First check of 1 complete
    >> Second result 2

whereas, either with choice==1 (or choice==0), I want the check_first_executionand second_execution (or check_first_executionand third_execution) to happen in parallel, for example with choice==1 :
    >> First result 1
    >> Second result 2
    >> First check of 1 complete
    

The function check_first_execution takes longer to execute so it should finish later than the second_execution function.
In the second part (# Second part), it also happened sequentially: second_execution -> check_second_execution -> second_execution -> check_second_execution ..., for example (with choice==1) :
    >> Second result 3
    >> Second check of 3 complete
    >> Second result 4
    >> Second check of 4 complete
    >> Second result 5
    >> Second check of 5 complete

what I want is something like this: second_execution -> second_execution -> check_second_execution -> second_execution..., example:
    >> Second result 3
    >> Second result 4
    >> Second check 3 complete
    >> Second result 5
    >> Second check 4 complete

How do I achieve the two points above?
Any help is appreciated.

First, when I run your code I get either First result 0 -> Third result 2 -> First check of value 1 complete or First result 1 -> Second result 2 -> First check of value 1 complete depending on the random choice generated, which is my understanding of what you want. So I cannot duplicate what you say is happening as far as the first part is concerned.
For the second part it is clear that the statement check_second = await check_second_execution(second_result) cannot be executed until second_result is returned from the statement second_result = await second_execution(first_result). So these two statements must by necessity be executed sequentially. But my understanding is that you want to run 5 instances of these two statement concurrently, one instance for each element of list_results_from_first. If my understanding is correct, the simplest approach is to create a new coroutine run_dependent_coroutines that will run the two sequential coroutines one after another:
...
async def main():
   ...
   # Second part

   async def run_dependent_coroutines(first_result):
      second_result = await second_execution(first_result)
      check_second = await check_second_execution(second_result)

   list_results_from_first = [result_from_first+i for i in range(5)]
   coroutines = [
      run_dependent_coroutines(first_result)
      for first_result in list_results_from_first
   ]
   await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

Prints:
First result 0
Third result 2
First check of value 0 complete
Second result 1
Second result 3
Second result 5
Second result 2
Second result 4
Second check of value 1 complete
Second check of value 5 complete
Second check of value 4 complete
Second check of value 3 complete
Second check of value 2 complete


See What should I do when someone answers my question?.

Thank you for your time and effort but please don't be snarky, I have already voted you up. I am waiting for other response before accepting your answer.

I wasn't trying to be 'snarky'.  I accidentally posted my comment to the wrong post where I was thanked for an answer by a new user but was not upvoted.
